# Please explain the meaning of the word "distance" in the sentence

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, synonyms, sentence

**Distance** sometimes lets you know who's worth keeping and who's worth letting go

Unless the **distance** is playing games with the vision and its all a mirage, a vagueness of a dream

Comment: Apart from my answer which tries to explain the meaning of the first sentence, is the meaning of the word "distance" itself unclear? It's the amount of space in between to objects, e.g. the distance between my house and my neighbour's is 25 meters.

Comment: The edit **dramatically** alters the question and almost invalidates the current answer. The question is **not** about the word *distance*, it's about the philosophical idea of "Absence makes the heart grow fonder" or "Out of sight, out of mind".

Comment: Do you have a source for your excerpt?

Answer (score 2):

Distance is the actual distance between people.

When you are far away from someone (you or they are in a far away country, for instance), you can tell by how this impacts your relationship whether they really are a good friend or not.

If you are apart from someone, and that person hardly contacts you anymore, or you do not contact them, they probably were not that close to you anyway.

It is entirely possible though that your relationship with them actually strengthens over that distance.

So the sentence can be read as:

> When there is a distance between you and your friends and near ones, you can sometimes find out which people are really close to you and which ones are not really that close.

Comment: +1 There is also the change in the perceiver's point of view. Proximity and constant contact may lead to complacence in a relationship whose importance only becomes apparent with its withdrawal.

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret your excerpt, **"distance"** can mean literal and figurative distance from another person (the opposite of closeness, or intimacy).  This **"distance"** can take the form of miles, time and emotional distance...all of which can impact the friendship or relationship.